# Oculus Rift Remote Control abutton click and a-frame mouse click

Tags: aframe

I developed a webVR project with a-frame. When I run this with the oculus rift, I can not click any box which has the mouse click event with the oculus remote control. Mouse leave and mouse enter are working but when ı click remote control's button , it can't click. Are not remote's click button and computers mouse button equivalent ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Oculus Remote is exposed through the Gamepad API rather than acting as a mouse, and you need to watch for button changes there. It's a controller with a button not a standard pointing device.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API/Using_the_Gamepad_API